# Google Search for main website

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search-results

If I search for my main domain in Google, it throws up structured data which contains links which do not have a lot of content (in fact some links don't have any content).

To give some clarity, in the below image, structured data(is that the correct name?) for moz shows up as below.  [image]

I presume that all the links that Google shows for moz are good content like (moz blog, moz pro etc.)

I have 2 questions

1. How does Google generate this structured data (in my case google generated it without any input from our side - note: we are a fairly new site and just started getting this view)
2. Why does google leave my other pages with good content and product pages and throw up links like track my order, blank category pages etc. in this structured data ?

Thanks. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are sitelinks, you can read all about this over here :
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Demote a sitelink URL:
On the Search Console Home page, click the site you want.
Under Search Appearance, click Sitelinks.
In the For this search result box, complete the URL for which you don't want a specific sitelink URL to appear. (How to find the right URL.)
In the Demote this sitelink URL box, complete the URL of the sitelink you want to demote.

As you see, you can demote these links. In short, you cannot say which Google has to show but you can say which he may not show.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks really useful pointer on site links and demotion. From the google link "We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them". Looks like for some reason google finds our blank categories rather than more useful content categories. Any ideas why this could be the case, what does Google Algorithm search for ? Marked as the answer since it answers my main question. Cheers.